# Reading multiple values from XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, logstash-configuration

I am trying to read an attribute from `Testng-result.xml` file , which contains the suite result and I want to read the Result Status and pass it into kibana, to get the result only  XPath query

```
xpath =>
   [
   "/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method/text()", "test-method",
   "/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[3]/@status/text()", "test-status",
   "/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']", "test-result"
   ]
```

This is the XML file:

```
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
  <suite name="TestSuite" duration-ms="498075" started-at="2018-06-13T07:00:21Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T07:08:39Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI" duration-ms="20867" started-at="2018-06-13T07:00:21Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T07:00:42Z">
      <class name="com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI">
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="testSetup()[pri:0, instance:com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI@7e0e6aa2]" name="testSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="14" started-at="2018-06-13T12:30:21Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T12:30:21Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- testSetup -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="beforeMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI@7e0e6aa2]" name="beforeMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="24" started-at="2018-06-13T12:30:21Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T12:30:21Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- beforeMethod -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="test()[pri:0, instance:com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI@7e0e6aa2]" name="test" duration-ms="19520" started-at="2018-06-13T12:30:21Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T12:30:40Z">
        </test-method> <!-- test -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="afterMethod()[pri:0, instance:com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI@7e0e6aa2]" name="afterMethod" is-config="true" duration-ms="172" started-at="2018-06-13T12:30:41Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T12:30:42Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- afterMethod -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="testTearDown()[pri:0, instance:com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI@7e0e6aa2]" name="testTearDown" is-config="true" duration-ms="2" started-at="2018-06-13T12:30:42Z" finished-at="2018-06-13T12:30:42Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- testTearDown -->
      </class> <!-- com.mtfilemedia.ifive.testscripts.UIHTML5TC10SettingSupportUI -->
    </test>
```

For this configuration I get the `test_status`, but not the test result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the attributes of a certain test-method identified by, e.g. the `name` attribute, the beginning of the XPath expression must find the desired test-method node, let's say you're looking for the one named "test":
`/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']`
To obtain any attribute of that element, you append the attribute axis to the expression. Thus you get these XPath expressions to access the attributes:

- status:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@status`
- signature:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@signature`
- name:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@name`
- is-config:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@is-config`
- duration-ms:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@duration-ms`
- started-at:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@started-at`
- finished-at:
  `/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@finished-at`

Your first XPath expression extracts text contents of all test-methods yielding only whitespace nodes.
Your second XPath expression is incorrect - an attribute has a value, but no text() child nodes (in fact, no child nodes at all). If you need to extract the value of an attribute as string, use the `string()` function, e.g. `string(/testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method[@name='test']/@status)`.
Your third XPath expression obtains the whole test-method element instead of its attributes.

Hope this helps.